# C++ possible #define something but used before

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am wondering if this is possible (for very easy use in project)

Say:

```
// array size (COUNT)
int foo[COUNT];

// values
foo[0] = 1;
foo[1] = 43;
foo[2] = 24;

// define (or equivalent) its size at the end
#define COUNT 3
```

(This is by design, so I don't have to fine tune it whenever I change the arrays length)

Thanks.

Edit:
What I am looking for is defining the size of the array after it has been filled with values. In the example I only know that it is 3 when I put values. So I could add 4 more "foo"s and only need to change the #define below.

Next Edit:

```
// this is the idea, can this be possible? or even a "forward" declared
int foobar = THEVALUE

// way further down
#define THEVALUE 5;
```

Comment: Okay, I voted to close and then got what you were asking. Anyway, the answer is no. Preprocessor macros are simple text substitution. You can't substitute what isn't defined yet.

Comment: @StoryTeller yeah that is what I want. If the macros were parsed in reverse, there would not be an issue. I have the array declared at the very start of my code, and way towards the  end I populate it.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You can reverse the close vote.

Comment: AFAIK there is no common tool-chain that supports what you are asking. In order to achieve it you'll need to find or create a C++ compliant preprocessor and use it in your build process instead of the one included with the tool chain. There's a good reason why this is not an available option - it's a _terrible_ idea!

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you need this? Seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @zenith Yeah, thinking it over, it is a bad idea and should just do the "standard" this is too "out of the box" thinking.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, thanks. I have no idea how I missed the retract vote button this entire time -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int foo[] = {1, 43, 24};
int const count = 3;    // See the SO array FAQ for how to compute this.
```

---

A simple type safe way to compute size, not mentioned in the SO array FAQ (because it was written before C++11), is

```
int const count = end( foo ) - begin( foo );
```

where `end` and `begin` are the `std` namespace functions from the `<iterator>` header.

See the [SO array FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) for other ways.

---

Generally, in modern C++ it is preferable to use `std::array` (fixed size) and `std::vector` (dynamic size) over raw arrays. This is safer and with more rich functionality, including in particular assignment and the ability to check the size easily. Unfortunately `std::array` does not support a size inferred from the initializer, so in this you'd have to use `std::vector` even if the array size is meant to be constant:

```
vector<int> foo = {1, 43, 24};

// foo.size() gives you the size at any moment.
```

Comment: Also, C++17 will have `std::size` as a free function.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf slightly what I want. I edited my first post, the last example shows exactly what I am thinking...

Comment: @EvanCarslake: I find it difficult to grok what you're really after. It's clearly an XY question: having a real problem X, envisioning an impractical Y as the solution, asking about Y, and not mentioning X. So what is X in your case. Is it, that you want to declare the array, fill it with values, and then be able to refer to its current size? That's what `std::vector` does for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize array with initializer list, then you don't need to know its size at all:

```
int foo[] = { 1, 43, 24 }
int size = sizeof(foo) / sizeof(int); // if you do need to know size
```

EDIT:
For a more idiomatic C++11 see the answer above :)

Comment: Teaching the type-unsafe C `sizeof` isn't nice. If you don't want to define anything, then better express the size in terms of standard `end` and `begin`.

Comment: the "more idiomatic" alternative you sketch won't work. It's a good idea to **try out** code before posting.

Comment: that might be because of an include of `<initializer_list>` in the code you're looking at. with that it will compile but does not define a `std::array`.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I had #include <iostream>, which includes <initializer_list>. Not an std::array indeed.